# How to draw a border around the content of a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm working on a document viewer. The document is displayed inside a `UIScrollView` so that it can be scrolled and zoomed. I need to draw a border around the document in order to separate it visually from the background of the `UIScrollView`. The border must not be zoomed together with the document -- it should maintain a constant thickness regardless of the zoom scale.

My current setup consists of a `UIScrollView` with two `UIView` children -- one for the document, and one for the border. I've overriden `viewForZoomingInScrollView`: to return the document view. I've also overridden `layoutSubviews` to center the document view (in case it's smaller than the `UIScrollView`) and then resize and position the border view behind it so that it looks like a frame. This works OK when the user is scrolling and zooming manually. But when I use `zoomToRect:animated:` to zoom programatically, layoutSubviews is called before the animation starts and my border view gets resized immediately with the document view catching up a bit later.

**Clarification: The border needs to be tightly fitting around the document view and not around the `UIScrollView` itself.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the problem with animated zooming. My setup is the same as described in the question. I just added some code to my `layoutSubview` implementation in order to detect any running `UIScrollView` animation and match it with a similar animation for resizing the border.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  // _pageView displays the document
  // _borderView represents the border around it

  . . .


  // _pageView is now centered -- we have to move/resize _borderView
  // layers backing a view are not implicitly animated
  // the following two lines work just fine if we don't need animation
  _borderView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frameToCenter.size.width + 2.0 * 15.0, frameToCenter.size.height + 2.0 * 15.0);
  _borderView.layer.position = _pageView.center;

  if (_pageView.layer.animationKeys.count > 0)
  {
    // UIScrollView is animating its content (_pageView)
    // so we need to setup a matching animation for _borderView

    [CATransaction begin];

    CAAnimation *animation = [_pageView.layer animationForKey:[_pageView.layer.animationKeys lastObject]];
    CFTimeInterval beginTime = animation.beginTime;
    CFTimeInterval duration = animation.duration;

    if (beginTime != 0.0) // 0.0 means the animation starts now
    {
      CFTimeInterval currentTime = [_pageView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
      duration = MAX(beginTime + duration - currentTime, 0.0);
    }

    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:animation.timingFunction];

    // calculate the initial state for _borderView animation from _pageView presentation layer
    CGPoint presentationPos = [_pageView.layer.presentationLayer position];
    CGRect presentationBounds = [_pageView.layer.presentationLayer frame];
    presentationBounds.origin = CGPointZero;
    presentationBounds.size.width += 2.0 * 15.0;
    presentationBounds.size.height += 2.0 * 15.0;

    CABasicAnimation *boundsAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    boundsAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:presentationBounds];
    boundsAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:_borderView.layer.bounds];
    [_borderView.layer addAnimation:boundsAnim forKey:@"bounds"];

    CABasicAnimation *posAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    posAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:presentationPos];
    posAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:_borderView.layer.position];
    [_borderView.layer addAnimation:posAnim forKey:@"position"];

    [CATransaction commit];
  }

}
```

It looks hacky but it works. I wish I didn't have to reverse engineer `UIScrollView` in order to make a simple border look good during animation...

Answer (score 3):

**Sample Code :**

```
yourScrollView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
yourScrollView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
yourScrollView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
yourScrollView.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

**Don't Forget :** `#Import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: the border must be around the content view and not around the scroll view itself

Comment: @itotsev : No Problem at all. You can use `yourContentView` at the place of `yourScrollView`. I was simply giving you the General Idea.

Comment: If I did that, when the user zooms the `UIScrollView`, the border would become thicker and I want it to be independent of the zoom scale.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to Import QuartzCore framework to your App.
then import that .h file on which class where you want to set the border.
like this.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Setup for Border.

```
ScrollView.layer.cornerRadius=5.0f;
ScrollView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
ScrollView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
ScrollView.layer.borderWidth= 4.0f;
```

check this one really helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Import QuartzCore framework:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now Add color to its view:

```
[scrollViewObj.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];

[scrollViewObj.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```